# Controlling the rotating object using CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am rotating object in a circular path using the following code:

```
CGRect boundingRect = CGRectMake(-25, -25, 50, 50);
orbit = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
orbit.keyPath = @"position";
orbit.path = CFAutorelease(CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(boundingRect, NULL));
orbit.duration = 4;
orbit.additive = YES;
orbit.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
orbit.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
orbit.speed = speed;

[_imageView.layer addAnimation:orbit forKey:@"orbit"];
```

Now, I want to control the rotating object to pause, resume, rotate in opposite direction, etc. I have found the way to pause and resume. But is there any way that I can rotate the object in to the opposite direction from which it was rotating after resuming.

I tried to rotate in to opposite direction by removing the animation to layer and adding the animation again. But in this case, the object is going out of the circular and come to the center. When i add the animation again, it goes to the circular path and starts rotate.

Is there any way to change the direction of rotation, while the object is rotating in circular path?

Following code is have used for pausing:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [_imageView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    _imageView.layer.speed = 0.0;
    _imageView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

Following code is using for resuming:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: The issue you are having is when starting rotation in the opposite direction, it doesn't start at the previous rotation?

Comment: Yes, eg:- If the object is rotating on clockwise direction, on click of anitclockwise button, it has to rotate in the opposite direction from the point it was rotating in clockwise, rather than coming to center and start again.